# How to Get the Memory Compressed value in TaskManager

Tags: memory, compression, taskmanager

Memory compression is a new feature in windows 10, and we can get the compression information in task manager.
[image]
My question is: How to get the Memory compression information programmatically? I have tried the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` but only get the memory in use(`MEMORYSTATUSEX.ullTotalPhys*dwMemoryLoad/100/(1024*1024*1024)`), But I can't find any member in `MEMORYSTATUSEX` is available.
Is there any way to get the Memory compression information?
Thanks

Comment: So far, no API can get this information, except seen in task manager. You could submit a request in feedback hub app on your behavior.